# Prince who was either a robot or a human who needed another heart

Tags: story-identification, novel, soft-sci-fi

The book as about a girl who worked in a bar or something similar, I'm not sure. There was also a prince who was either a robot or a human who needed another heart. His heart needs constant replacement. There was also a man who gave his heart to the prince. At the end, the prince and the girl meet and fall in love. The prince doesn't need another heart anymore.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! When did you read this? If you remember any more details please [edit] them in - [this helpful checklist for story-identification questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335) might help

Comment: Was this a medieval setting or a high tech setting (or neither)? I have a frustratingly vague memory of a story that starts with a prince in disguise meeting up with his best friend, and the prince has some form of heart condition that will soon kill him. Possibly a magical disease or curse. But in this story it turns out the prince is the bad guy and I think the girl ends up with the prince's friend.

Answer (score 8):

This sounds like the children's novel [*Clockwork, or All Wound Up*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clockwork_(novel)) by Philip Pullman, published in the United Kingdom in 1996, then in the United States in 1998.

[image]

The plot description below is from Wikipedia:

> Clockwork is set in the town of Glockenheim in Germany in "the old days". It has three main characters: Karl, an apprentice clockmaker who has failed to make a figure for the town clock; Gretl, who is a very selfless young girl is also one of the main characters and is the daughter of the innkeeper of Glockenheim and Fritz, a local writer whose unfinished story sets the gears of Clockwork turning.
>
> The townspeople gather in the White Horse Tavern the evening before a new figure for their town clock made by Karl is to be unveiled. Karl, however, admits to Fritz that he has not made the figure, the first apprentice in hundreds of years to fail to do so.
> The people in the tavern listen to Fritz read his latest story about a local aristocrat, Prince Otto, and his young son, Prince Florian. Prince Otto dies while on a hunting trip. His heart has been replaced with a clockwork mechanism that enables him to drive his son home in their sledge. Fritz wrote down the story after having a dream, but he has not thought of an ending for it, and hopes that he will be able to think up one on the spot: "He was just going to wind up the story, set it going, and make up the end when he got there."
>
> The story begins to come true when Dr. Kalmeneius comes to the door of the tavern. Fritz flees in terror. Dr. Kalmeneius offers Karl a figure called Sir Ironsoul, a clockwork knight, which Karl accepts. A price must be paid for this gift, as Sir Ironsoul comes alive and kills anyone who says the word "Devil". Only the song "The Flowers of Lapland" can stop him.
>
> The narrative shifts back and forwards through time. It is revealed that Prince Florian was made from clockwork by Dr. Kalmeneius at the wishes of his father. His mechanical heart will soon wind down. Gretl is the only person who can restore true life to him. All the stories come together as one. Karl places Prince Florian in the clock's tower as his apprentice piece. Karl is killed by Sir Ironsoul. Gretl finishes the journey by bringing Prince Florian to life through her unselfish love.